# CakePHP 3 Getting a Associated table from another table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have 3 tables Product Styles Details

```
Product < Styles        < details
id      < product_id FK < styles_id FK
```

My relationships so far are

```
//ProductTable 
$this->hasMany('Styles', [
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id'
    ]);

//StyleTable 
 $this->belongsTo('Products', [
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id'
    ]);
$this->hasMany('Details', [
        'foreignKey' => 'style_id'
    ]);
//Detail
$this->belongsTo('Styles', [
        'foreignKey' => 'style_id'
    ]);
```

In my details controller under index(), I add

```
$this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Styles’, ‘Products’]
    ];
```

Styles work, but Products doesn’t work. I get an error
Details is not associated with Product. That makes sense I didn’t define it in the Details Table. I’m not sure how to start, or what it is called.

A far left join?

I have tried

```
//Detail Table
$this->belongsTo('Product', [
        'foreignKey' => 'product_style_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'product_id',
        'joinTable' => 'product_styles'
    ]);
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out

```
 'contain' => ['Styles’, ‘Styles.Products’]
```

This works